# integral of a (cotan) rational function

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to solve the following integral:

$$\int \frac{1}{1+\cot^3(x)}dx$$

While the solution can be found in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201/%281%2bcot%5E3%28x%29%29), I am not completely sure how to reduce the above integral to get the solution referenced. Pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: On Courant and John first volume of _Calculus_, there is a section called **Integration of some other kind of functions**. There, under the subsection "Integration of $R\big(\cos(x),\sin(x)\big)$", you should find the proper way to solve the integral. Looking at the solution given by _WA_, it might be a good idea to transform the integrand to the form $\frac{du}{u}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=\cot(x)$; then $dx = -\frac{1}{u^2+1}du$.  Now the integral becomes

$$
I = - \int \frac{1}{(u^2+1)(u^3+1)} du 
$$

which can be resolved into partial fractions as:

$$
I =- \int  \frac{1-2u}{3(u^2-u+1)} + \frac{u+1}{2(u^2+1)} + \frac{1}{6u+6}  du
$$

each sub-integral of which can be readily evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the change of variables $ x=\arctan(t) $ you get

$$ \int \!{\frac {{t}^{3}}{ \left( 1+{t}^{3} \right)  \left( 1+{t}^{2}
 \right) }}{dt}\,.
 $$